# Solve the integral $\int_0^1 x^{\frac{1}{3}}(1-x)^{\frac{2}{3}}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, beta-function, open-map

I would like to consider two ways to compute the (real) integral $\int_{0}^{1}x^{\frac{1}{3}}(1-x)^{\frac{2}{3}}dx$ using complex analysis:

**(i)**  By residues

**(ii)** By Beta function

**My computations**:

**(i)** First of all, my intuition is that the value of the integral should be either $0$ or another real value.

$x^{\frac{1}{3}}(1-x)^{\frac{2}{3}}$ has two singularities in 0 and 1. Therefore, $\sqrt[3]{z(1-z)^2}$ is well defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,1]$ and $\int_{|z|=\varepsilon}\sqrt[3]{z(1-z)^2}dz \leq 2\pi \varepsilon k \rightarrow 0$, as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$, for some constant $k$.

$\int_{\gamma_\varepsilon}\sqrt[3]{z(1-z)^2}dz\rightarrow 3\int_0^1 x(1-x)^2dx$, as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$.

Now we need to find the Laurent expansions at the singularities.

*For $z=0$*

$\sqrt[3]{z(1-z)^2} = \sqrt[3]{z^3-2z^2+z}=z\sqrt[3]{1-\frac{2}{z}+\frac{1}{z^2}}$ and fixing $w=\frac{2}{z}-\frac{1}{z^2}$. Hence, using the binomial formula for $(1-w)^{1/3}$, we get

$(1-w)^{1/3}=1+\frac{w}{3}-\frac{w^2}{9}+\frac{5w^3}{3}+\dots$

Plugging back the value of $w$:

$z(1-w)^{1/3}=z(1+\frac{\frac{1}{z}(2-\frac{1}{z})}{3}-\frac{\frac{1}{z^2}(2-\frac{1}{z})^2}{9}+\dots)=z+\frac{2-1/z}{3}-\frac{(2-1/z)^2}{9z}+\dots$

As a result, the residue is $(-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{4}{9})\frac{1}{z}=-\frac{7}{9}\frac{1}{z}$

*For $z=1$*

$\sqrt[3]{z(1-z)^2}=\sqrt[3]{(z-1)^2(z-1+1)}=\sqrt[3]{(z-1)^3+(z-1)^2}=(z-1)\sqrt[3]{1-\frac{-1}{z-1}}=(z-1)(1-\frac{1}{3(z-1)}-\frac{1}{9(z-1)^2}+\dots)$

Hence, the residue for $z=1$ is $-\frac{1}{9}$

By the Cauchy-Riemann integral formula, we have

$\int_{|z|=\varepsilon}\sqrt[3]{z(1-z)^2}dz=2\pi i(-\frac{8}{9})$ which is complex-valued.

**(ii)** Using the Beta function $f(m,n)=\int_0^1x^{m-1}(1-x)^{n-1}=\frac{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(m+n)}$, for $m-1=1/3$ and $n-1=2/3$, we get:

$\int_0^1 x^{\frac{1}{3}}(1-x)^{\frac{2}{3}}dx=\frac{\Gamma(4/3)\Gamma(5/3)}{\Gamma(3)}=\frac{\frac{1}{3}\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})\frac{2}{3}\Gamma(\frac{2}{3})}{2!}=\frac{1}{9}\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})\Gamma(1-\frac{1}{3})=\frac{1}{9}\frac{\pi}{\sin\frac{\pi}{3}}=\frac{1}{9}\pi\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{2\sqrt{3}\pi}{27}$

Could someone please help me to understand where the mistake is?

Comment: Why do you say that there are singularities at $0$ and $1$?

Comment: Branch points, indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to use [Cauchy's residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) (not to be confused with the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations), BTW) to evaluate this integral.  To use the residue theorem, you need to integrate over a closed contour in the complex plane.  As far as I can tell, you don't have one;  you're just adding up all the residues that you can find.  This is not a valid approach.

It is probably possible to find a closed contour in the complex plane that allows you to evaluate this integral.  Note, however, that the integrands has [branch points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point) at 0 and 1, which means that you have to be careful in what counts as a "closed contour" for the purposes of the residue theorem.

Comment: thanks. This is what I tried to do. I defined the path $\gamma_\varepsilon$ around the branch points $0$ and $1$. Could you please tell me why summing up the residues is not a valid approach in this case? Which alternative would you consider? Is the beta function result correct?

Comment: @FunnyBuzer:  You haven't actually said what your contour in the complex plane is, or which part of it relates to the integral on the real axis that you're trying to evaluate.  Without knowing this, it's impossible to tell whether the branch points are enclosed in the contour or not.